# Why is the_permalink only echoing the base category?

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I am running the following code on Wordpress:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li><?php the_permalink() ?>,<?php the_ID() ?></li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

But it is returning an incorrect URL. For instance, one post may return:

```
/disastersafety/last-minute-actions-flooding-imminent/
```

However, when clicked, that URL actually is

```
/ibhs/ibhs-risks/ibhs-risk-flood/last-minute-actions-flooding-imminent/
```

How can I get Wordpress to echo the actual correct URL?

Comment: there is a chance that you have the link in /ibhs/ibhs-risks/ page?

Comment: If you assign several categories to one post it will generate a permalink with the category which has the lower number (ID). This is done to prevent showing the same content via different URLs which is not good for SEO and to actually make sense of the whole permalink concept - a single URL for the single piece of content. The difference between category permalinks and single posts (or custom post types) permalinks is handled by permalink settings and custom permalink rules. You should inspect your permalink structures using plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/